# How to compile Overleaf LaTeX template in VS code using LaTeX workshop?

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, overleaf, compilation-error, visual-studio-code

I am trying to compile the following template : https://www.overleaf.com/articles/ismail-shaikhs-business-cv/hwqzkdzjtpcb on VS code version with LaTeX workshop version 8.4.1.

The .tex file compiles and works perfectly on Overleaf. However, when trying to use VS code to compile the PDF, I get the following error:

[image]

In the problems part this is what I get :
[image: Problems log]

I ignore why the same document compiles in Overleaf but fails to compile in VS code with LaTeX workshop.

OS : Ubuntu 18.04
Virtual Studio Code Extension : LaTeX workshop 8.4.1

Comment: Try if it works if you give the folder of the file a sane name, that means without all these `%20` and `(1)` and apostrophs.

Comment: Thank you very much ! that worked

Comment: Hello! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. It seems that the template itself contains an error: there is `\cvskill{CCNA & CCNP}{4}` on line 64, which should be `\cvskill{CCNA \& CCNP}{4}` (`&` -> `\&`). Is it possible that this is causing the error?

Comment: Yes definitely, it was both the (& -> \&) error and the file name, it is compiling correctly now. Thank you very much